# Regex to split string in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to group strings based on character.

For eg. I want to split following url in two groups

```
group 1 -   /viewarticle/abd-fdj-gfg-to
group2 - 628882 (last string)

/viewarticle/abd-fdj-gfg-to-628882
```

I tried this " -(?!.*-) " but it is not working.

I have to use only regex not split function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use groups `()` with `.*-` to capture the first input and the rest as second so use:

```
(.*-)([a-zA-Z\\d]+)
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Dtp4gt)

```
val regex = "(.*-)([a-zA-Z\\d]+)".toRegex() // use only (\\d+) for digits
val matchResults = regex.find("/viewarticle/abd-fdj-gfg-to-628882")!!
val (link, id) = matchResults.destructured
println("Link: $link \nID: $id")
```

Details:

`.*-` : match anything till last `-`

`[a-zA-Z\\d]+` : match 0 or more characters `a-zA-Z` or digits

Answer (score 3):

You may try splitting using a lookbehind, e.g. split on:

```
(?<=-to)-
```

You could also make the lookbehind more specific:

```
(?<=abd-fdj-gfg-to)-
```

But this would only make sense if what precedes `-to` would always be the same.

**Edit:**

If you need to split on the *last* hyphen, then use the negative lookahead:

```
-(?!.*-)
```

Comment: this string could be anything. I have to extract last string after -

Comment: @Ragini Then split on `-(?!.*-)` ... this will split on the last hyphen